# Custom Post type Query by Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

This has been driving me nuts for hours. I've checked numerous pages on the web for an answer but I can't find one. I'm trying to get all of the posts from a custom post type, that are attached to an array of taxonomy ids. Here's the code

```
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'contractors',
            'showposts' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'terms' => $taxarray,
                    'field' => 'id'
                )
            )
        );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

If you're wondering about the variables...

```
$taxonomy="service_type"; //and yes, this exists
$taxarray = array(24); //and yes, this id exists, and yes it has custom post types attached.
```

Basically, when I print_r($query), no posts are returned. Of course, I see all the other junk that spits out of it, but there's no posts. I'm pulling my hair out over this.

EDIT: I don't know if this is helpful, but a couple of things should be noted. I'm trying to do this inside a custom class->function, and I'm on the latest wordpress, and php 5+.

EDIT #2: New pastebin with fuller code: http://pastebin.com/px9N4LCV

FINAL EDIT: I figured out why it wasn't working. I was running the query too early, and Wordpress wasn't recognizing my taxonomy yet.

Comment: Try replacing "showposts" with "posts_per_page"

Comment: Tried that, didn't change anything. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Try adding 'operator' => 'IN'

Comment: I had that in there earlier, it didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `showposts` was replaced by `posts_per_page` in wordpress 2.1. [See pagination parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters). Also note that `print_r($query)` won't return any results because $query variables is WP_Query object; you need to exceute the query.

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'contractors',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms' => $taxarray,
                'field' => 'id'
            )
        )
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$results = $query->get_posts();
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Thanks cybnet, I tried that, but no dice.

Comment: Read again the answer, I added more info

Comment: Nope, still not producing anything. Let me try something real fast.

Comment: Nope, nevermind my Edit to my question, where I ask about location of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you update your question with your full code and some more iformation like where are you executing the code. I've tested the code I posted and it works perfectly.

Comment: Check this out. http://pastebin.com/px9N4LCV

Comment: @willbeeler I checked your code and found you are using wrong Contractor_model object name that is $contrator , it should be $contractor

Comment: Also, as I said in the answer, you are not executing any method thar returns the posts: You need to make `$query->get_posts();`, [start the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) or any other method that returns the posts.

Comment: and in print_r() function just use found_posts property to know how many posts have found like print_r($contractor->get_ids_from_tax('service_type', $_GET['service_type'])->found_posts);

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry.. I just typed some of that up real quickly in Pastebin. I only showed the part that I was working on at the time. Here's the full class/function (there's more to the class but has nothing to do with this). http://pastebin.com/PjtriQgX

Comment: The real issue, is that I'm not getting anything from the query.. That's my problem, it's not grabbing posts. The function file is included in the functions.php file in my template, but has no other problems. I use the class all over the site and there's no issues there. I even tried query_posts which was a waste of time.

Comment: This is the result of the WP_Query object after the query: http://pastebin.com/qnjLmjqL

Comment: The code I posted works perfectly. Test that code outside the class and if it works you should start to build again your class step by step checking that all goes fine after each change. Looking at your WP_Query object it seems fine, you should check also the post, taxonomy and term you are trying to get/filter.

Comment: Could there be conflicts with query_posts()? Do you know?

Comment: In your class you are using a new instance of WP_Query, so I don't think it conflicts with `query_posts()`. Anyway, I recomend avoid the use of query_posts() and use [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post), [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or a [new WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) beacuse [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) alter the main query and need to be used with a lot of care.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help. I figured out why it wasn't working. I was running the query too early, and Wordpress wasn't recognizing my taxonomy yet. The code that I displayed was working, and it runs just fine, but I ran it too early. Thanks!